# Casting pointers other than void* to and from integers

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

According to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer), `intptr_t` is, in implementations that support it, a type which can hold a pointer to `void`. So a value of type `void*` can be converted to `intptr_t` (or `uintptr_t`) and back giving the same value. But pointers to different types needn't have the same size.

All pointers to objects can be converted to `void*` and back with roundtripping guarantee. There seems, however, not to be any requirement that actually `void*` is at least as wide as any pointer to object type. Is it therefore safe to cast between `intptr_t` and `T*` for any object type `T` and expect roundtripping? Or should an intermediate cast to `void*` be added in each direction?

Comment: Interestingly, [the C version](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) says only "integer type capable of holding a pointer". So it would seem that pointers to any object type and even function pointers are fair game there, unlike in C++.

Comment: From that linked reference regarding `intptr_t`: "signed integer type capable of holding a pointer to `void`" Which means its size will be at least as big as `void*`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, it doesn't mean that. The representation of pointers isn't specified by the standard and can have arbitrary redundancy.

Comment: I should also add that it's casting from `intprt_t` to `void*` and back that's guaranteed to give the same integer. On the other hand, different values of a pointer type can point to the same object (or be null). And there's no guarantee that converting even the same integer twice will give the same pointer, just a pointer to the same object.

Comment: The same is true about converting between pointer types. Roundtripping is meant in a weak sense, namely that even though the pointer after converting there and back isn't required to equal the original, the pointed to object (or lack thereof for null pointers) must be the same.

Comment: Yea, you're right that when converting between `void*` and `T*`, equality of the pointer (and not just pointed to object's existence and identity) is actually guaranteed, contrary to my previous comment.

Comment: Any pointer to an object can be converted to [a pointer to `void`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_void). This pointer to `void` can then be converted to e.g. `intptr_t`. Then you can convert that back to a pointer to `void`, which can be converted back to a pointer to the original object. There's no guarantees about things like bitwise representation, only that these conversions are valid and will not loose the original object.

Comment: Also note that these conversions only goes for pointers to *objects*, not pointers to functions. A pointer to a function is not (per the specification) implicitly convertible to `void*`. IIRC the same goes for pointers to members (static, non-static, functions or non-functions).

Comment: Unlike in C, where all types of pointers can be (and directly) converted losslessly to `intptr_t` (if it exist on a given implementation) and back, right?

Comment: No, in C pointers to functions are not really compatible with `void*` either. There are systems still in use where a pointer to a function can't be represented as a pointer to an object. It's unlikely that any of us would encounter such a system though. :)

Comment: But in C (not sure in C++) function pointers can be converted one to another independently of the signature they represent. But it yields undefined behaviour *calling* a function through an incompatible function pointer.